# How to declare XML datatype in netezza during DDL

Tags: xml, netezza

I have a VARCHAR in my netezza table - This varchar is resembles XML and I want to use XML functions on it - how do i declare this column as an XML data type?
Do I do it at the DDL stage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netezza [does not support](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.0/com.ibm.nz.sqltk.doc/c_sqlext_user_type_xml.html) XML storage as its own data type. You have already declared it correctly--as a varchar.

You can perform [XML functions](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.0/com.ibm.nz.sqltk.doc/c_sqlext_xml_reference.html) on this column as long as `IsValidXML()` returns true.